# How can I remove the element that is clicked, instead of all items being deleted except the item clicked?

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

This is from a react native tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSRrxpdMpVc

The app is for putting down what your 'course goals' are. It's basically just a ToDo list. You can add goals and remove them.

To try and get my head around it I thought I'd try and do the 'delete' code myself. I want to know how I can make my method work:

```
export default function App() {
      const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);

      function addGoalHandler(goalTitle) {
        setCourseGoals([goalTitle, ...courseGoals]);
      }

      function removeGoalHandler(index) {
        console.log(index)
        setCourseGoals(courseGoals.splice(index, 1));
      }

      return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>

          <GoalInput onAddGoal={addGoalHandler}/>

          <ScrollView>
            {courseGoals.map((goal, index) => <GoalItem onDelete={() => removeGoalHandler(index)} title={goal} key={index}/>)}
          </ScrollView>


        </View>
      );
    }
```

What I thought would happen on line 10 is that the `courseGoals` array would be set to `courseGoals` minus the spliced element. Instead, I have discovered that splice actually returns the deleted item. How can I fix this? Is there no way to just get `courseGoals.splice()` to return the array without the spliced element?

Comment: `splice` modifies the array it’s used on. Make a copy first, then splice the copy, then set the state to the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `slice`:

```js
function removeGoalHandler(index) {
  console.log(index);
  setCourseGoals([...courseGoals.slice(0, index), ...courseGoals.slice(index + 1)]);
}
```

or with `splice`:

```js
function removeGoalHandler(index) {
  console.log(index);
  const courseGoalsCopy = [...courseGoals];
  courseGoalsCopy.splice(index, 1);
  setCourseGoals(courseGoalsCopy);
}
```